# Querying a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Can someone help me add the third table in this query containing risk factors for diseases. The table is tblRiskFactors

```
SELECT tblDiseases.disease
FROM tblRel 
   LEFT JOIN tblDiseases ON tblRel.diseaseID = tblDiseases.diseaseID
WHERE tblRel.symptomID = '1' AND tblRel.symptomID = '2' AND tblRel.symptomID ='3'
```

Comment: Could you give structures of tables?

Comment: You really need to give us more to go on here. Could you provide the structure of the three tables and how you're looking to JOIN them?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  tblDiseases.disease
FROM    tblRel 
        LEFT JOIN tblDiseases 
            ON tblRel.diseaseID = tblDiseases.diseaseID
        LEFT JOIN tblRiskFactors
            ON -- define the linking condition here
WHERE   tblRel.symptomID = '1' AND 
        tblRel.symptomID = '2' AND 
        tblRel.symptomID = '3'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tblDiseases.disease as disease 
FROM tblRel 
   LEFT JOIN tblDiseases ON tblRel.diseaseID = tblDiseases.diseaseID
   LEFT JOIN tblRiskFactors ON tblRel.relation_column = tblRiskFactors.relation_column
WHERE tblRel.symptomID in (1,2,3)
```